# How to add the deviation from the mean on a geom_line with geom_smooth?

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

Is it possible to add a kind of smooth band with the absolute values of the distance from the mean on a geom_line?

I have a matrix like this:

```
                   mean       Date            abs(mean-observed_value)
1                  0.2955319   2015-08-04        1.167321e-02
2                  0.2802859   2015-08-12        7.537708e-03
3                  0.2671653   2015-08-20        2.074987e-03
4                  0.2552016   2015-08-28        4.883826e-03
5                  0.2554279   2015-09-05        4.419968e-03
```

On the abs(mean-observed_value) column  there are many time series of 54 observations each one, and the Date and mean are like the groups, been repeated for each 54 rows. I was plotting all the time series (using the proper `value`, like this:

```
p<-ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = y_m, aes(x = Date, y = value, group = variable), color="steelblue", size =0.1) 
p + geom_line(data =y_mean, aes(x = Date, y = as.numeric(df.ts_mean)), color=1, size =2) + ylab("EVI")
```

[image]

But now with the deviations I want to plot them as a smooth band. Something like this:
[image]

I would appreciate a lot any possible solutions! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `geom_ribbon` from `ggplot2()` package where You can set up `ymin` and `ymax` values (in Your case it will be the **abs** column), here is an example code:

```
library(ggplot2)
huron <- data.frame(year = 1875:1972, level = as.vector(LakeHuron))
h <- ggplot(huron, aes(year))
h + geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = level - 1, ymax = level + 1), fill = "grey70") + 
  geom_line(aes(y = level))
```

Please for the future post sample data as `dput()` output, it is much easier to use it, rather then copying each value!